# IEnumerable doesn't have a Count method

Tags: c#, asp.net, enumerable

I have the following method:

```
public bool IsValid
{
  get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
}

public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations(){
  //code here
}
```

Why is it that when I do `.Count()` above it is underlined in red?

I got the following error:

> Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Count' and no extension method
>   'Count' accepting a first argument of
>   type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\users\a\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\NerdDinner\NerdDinner\Models\Dinner.cs  15  47  NerdDinner

Comment: Had same problem. For some reason you can't right-click this and choose "Resolve ..." to fix it :(

Comment: Sigh!  I have System.Linq included but still get this error.  (Though he error message names the first arg as "System.Linq.IQueryable".)

Comment: On a general note: Be way of the shortcomings of .Count() - don't use it lightheartedly! I've written about it in my comment below https://stackoverflow.com/a/65112753/863651 Feel free to review it

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your source and make sure you've got a reference to the System.Core assembly.

[`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357758(v=VS.100).aspx) is an extension method provided by the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345746(v=VS.100).aspx) static class for LINQ to Objects, and [`System.Linq.Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable(v=VS.100).aspx) for LINQ to SQL and other out-of-process providers.

EDIT: In fact, using `Count()` here is relatively inefficient (at least in LINQ to Objects). All you want to know is whether there are *any* elements or not, right? In that case, `Any()` is a better fit:

```
public bool IsValid
{
  get { return !GetRuleViolations().Any(); }
}
```

Comment: If this reference gives you an error, verify that the Target Framework of your project (in the project properties, Application tab) is set to .NET Framework 3.5 or 4. Extension methods won't work on 2.0 or earlier.

Comment: I've had the using System.Linq; but it doesn't resolve my issue... how can I make sure that I got a reference to the System.Core assembly?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I fixed it... what is the different between System.data.linq and System.Linq

Comment: @Alexander: They're entirely different namespaces. `System.Data.Linq` is  specific to LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Maybe it should be revised in the NerdDinner tutorial that I am using as it uses Count instead of Any

Comment: @Alexander: Quite possibly :)

Comment: @skyfoot: I have no idea what you're referring to. Where is it out by 1?

Comment: @skyfoot: No, it really won't. It will give you 4. If you think otherwise, please post a question with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Applying the extension method Count to IEnumerable<T> is problematic since an IEnumerable may contain an infinite number of elements, e.g.

IEnumerable<T> GetInfinite() {
  while (true) yield return 0;
}

Answer (score 12):

`Any()` or `Count()` methods in Linq work only for generic types.

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

If you have a simple `IEnumerable` without a type, try to use

```
IEnumerable<object>
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumeration` does not have a method called `Count()`. It's just a kind of "sequence of elements". Use for example `List` if you explicitly need the number of elements.
If you use Linq keep in mind, that the extension method `Count()` may actually re-count the number of elements each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

**[A short & sweet general word of caution on the pitfalls of .Count()](https://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-12/linq-count-considered-occasionally-harmful/) to help the weary traveler that stumbles upon this post in the future!**

Short story:

The following works -no doubt- but there *might* small performance penalty if the enumerables is **not** backed by an underlying array or list which has the 'count' in handy/precomputed:

```
public bool IsValid
{
   get { return SomeMethodReturningEnumerable().Count() <= threshold; }  <--- small performance issue here
}

public IEnumerable<SomeObject> SomeMethodReturningEnumerable(){
   yield return foo;
   yield return bar; etc
}
```

The call to the .Count() method will probably go through each and every item in the enumerable and **then** compare the overall count against threshold. We being smarter can do a bit better:

```
    public bool IsValid
    {
       get { return !SomeMethodReturningEnumerable().HasMoreThan(threshold); }  <--- neato!
    }

    public static bool HasLessThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count) => !sequence.HasMoreThan(count - 1);

    public static bool HasLessOrEqualTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count) => !sequence.HasMoreThan(count);

    public static bool HasMoreOrEqualTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count) => sequence.HasMoreThan(count - 1);

    public static bool HasMoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count) => sequence.EnumerationCounterImpl(count, equals_vs_greaterThan: false);

    public static bool HasExactly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count) => sequence.EnumerationCounterImpl(count, equals_vs_greaterThan: true);

    public static bool EnumerationCounterImpl<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int count, bool equals_vs_greaterThan = true) //0
    {
        if (equals_vs_greaterThan && count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(count)} is less than zero!");

        if (!equals_vs_greaterThan && count < 0)
            return true;

        var staticCount = (sequence as ICollection)?.Count                              
                          ?? (sequence as ICollection<T>)?.Count
                          ?? (sequence as IReadOnlyCollection<T>)?.Count;

        if (staticCount != null)
            return staticCount > count;

        using (var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator()) //1 optimization
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++)
            {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    continue;

                return false;
            }

            return !equals_vs_greaterThan //     ==
                   || enumerator.MoveNext(); //  >
        }

        //0 https://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-12/linq-count-considered-occasionally-harmful/
        //1 using the enumerator directly is slightly faster than using LINQ methods   it avoids allocating an extra iterator
        //  state machine compared to using skip()
    }
```

There! Problem solved again but this time around we are performance-conscious!

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return (GetRuleViolations().Cast<RuleViolation>().Count() == 0); }
}
```