# Error Accessing namespace Library c#

Tags: c#, streamreader, readline

This is more of conceptual question, since I am new to C# trying to get a simplified understanding.

My is trying to read lines from text file, which works fine but I am trying to implement following solution to read the last line as well but it gives following error :

> Error  1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

    class Program
    {          
        public static void Main()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            string xml_files;
            // string jpg_files;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\test\logfile_c#.txt");

            string lastLine = File.ReadLines(@"C:\test\logfile_c#.txt").Last();

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.WriteLine(counter);
                Console.Read();
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me understand better how to avoid this.

Thanks!!

Comment: an old post here (answers your question) answered by @John Skeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659290/ienumerable-doesnt-have-count

Answer (score 4):

You just need:

```
using System.Linq;
```

[`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345746.aspx), and extension methods are discovered via `using` directives, basically.

It's probably worth reading up about [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) and all the bits of the language that come together to make it work, rather than learning little bits piecemeal.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding the following line at the top:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import System.Linq

```
using System.Linq;
```