# Unit test the count in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, unit-testing

I am writing some unit tests for my MVC 5 internet application. I have a service class that returns the following:

```
IEnumerable<Account>
```

I am writing a unit test to check the number of items in the returned `IEnumerable<Account>`.

Because `IEnumerable` does not have a `.Count()` function, how should I check the number of items in the returned `IEnumerable`? Should I convert this `IEnumerable` to a `List`, and then do the `Count`? Is there a better way or more official way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does have a [count method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659292/182821) via extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` **does** have a [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) method, via LINQ.

Whether you call `Count()` or `ToList().Count`, the bottom line is the same: It's going to enumerate the entire collection. It doesn't matter which approach you use. The exception is if the underlying collection is an `ICollection<T>`. In that case, it will skip enumerating the entire collection and just return the `Count` property of the `ICollection`.

From a testing perspective, you probably don't care about the **number** of `Account`s returned: You care that the **correct** `Account`s were returned. I would rewrite my tests accordingly.