# Getting the count of an IEnumerable list?

Tags: c#

In my code, I am attempting to output the amount of items in my movie list from a console command, but I'm not entirely sure on how I'd be able to grab the amount of items from the list.  The list is originally created as a private list, but I have a property making it an IEnumerable list, shown below.

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies
        {
            get
            {
                return this.movies;
            }
        }
```

How would I be able to count how many items are within the list that is given by the property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto: Count the items from a IEnumerable<T> without iterating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IEnumerable doesn't have a Count method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659290/ienumerable-doesnt-have-a-count-method)

Answer (score 4):

What is the problem with calling the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Movies.Count();
```

You will need `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: I didn't have that namespace so I couldn't see the option.  Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

If your collection actually *is* a list you can cast it back instead of using the `Count()`-method, that `IEnumerable` provides. Not sure if `List.Count()` will internally call `List.Count` - but I expect it to. Anyway here´s the code for the cast:

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies
{
    get
    {
        return this.movies;
    }
}

var theList = instance.Movies as IList<Movie>();
if (theList != null) 
    count = theList.Count;
else 
    count = instance.Movies.Count();
```